# Streaming from RxJava API Web Endpoint

Tags: websocket, streaming, rx-java2

I've just finished working through a book and RxJava, and whilst it answered a lot of questions I had, one still remains. How do I take a stream and allow a client to subscribe to it over HTTP (i.e. keep an open connection and stream events as they occur upstream)?

I'm content with the server-side details, but sending that to a client via HTTP seems to be a challenge. Whilst gRPC could be a great option, it's not supported in browsers. [The Streams Spec](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) looks like a good option once it is implemented. However, at this point in time, those are not viable options.

To achieve streaming functionality (e.g. from a, I presume, REST/JSON API to a client web-site), am I looking at SocksJS / websockets? Or is there some other protocol that can be harnessed?